# Iron.io worker + Laravel 4 - mcrypt extension required

Tags: php, laravel-4, mcrypt, ironworker, iron

I am trying Iron Workers with Laravel 4. I managed to upload the code but it can't run it on the server because Laravel requires mcrypt extension. Does anyone know how can I install it on iron servers? I followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/iron-io/iron_worker_examples/tree/master/php/laravel) but they don't say anything about this problem.

Thanks,
Cezar

Answer (score 0):

Cezar, you can try [this package](https://github.com/iron-io/laraworker) to integrate IronWorker to your Laravel app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know about this package but unfortunately the same problem appears. I think I need to install php5-mcrypt package from iron but I didn't manage to find a way to install packages - http://dev.iron.io/worker/reference/environment/.

Comment: I have just seen that the package is created by you, nice. How do you install mcrypt in your library because I didn't see anything in UploadWorker.php ?

Comment: I discovered the problem. I configured the stack to be 5.5 but it seems that only 5.4 has mcrypt installed. Unfortunately our app actually needs php 5.5 in a couple of places. I believe your library is using 5.4 as well and this is why the problem didn't appear.